# "He was timed in 1 minute and 35 seconds." Can I say like this?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

This is what Google Translator outputs:

> The runner **was timed in** 1 minute and 35 seconds.

I am not sure about "was timed in" meaning that the official timer showed "1 min 35 sec" after the runner finished the race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal phrasing is "timed **at**" when we're talking about the length of time something is measured to take.  For example,

> [Holder's time was two minutes 38.22 seconds while Small was **timed at** two minutes 39. 82 seconds.](http://barpublish.bits.baseview.com/321161786759638.php)

Comment: I guess I can also say like this: "The coach timed Tom at three minutes 20.25 seconds." (by inserting a name or noun between "timed" and "at")?

Comment: Correct!  "Tom was timed at three minutes 20.25 seconds" is the passive voice, "The coach timed Tom at three minutes 20.25 seconds" is the active voice.  I think for *timed at* the passive voice is almost more common than the active voice, because we usually care more about the thing being timed than the person doing the timing.